# Clearing thread locals in a thread pooled environment

Tags: spring, threadpool, thread-local

We are having some values stored in thread local variables and we are using thread pooling with Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, so we have to clear the thread local variables once a task is executed. We tried providing a custom ThreadFactory and wrapper for Runnable to see whether we can clear the thread locals after a task is executed. But the line after the runnable.run() is never executed, see code below. Want to know whether I am doing something wrong or I misunderstood something and the right way to implement what I want, which is to clear the thread local variables in a thread pool environment.

```
    // ThreadPoolTaskExecutor configuration
    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("default_task_executor_thread");
        executor.setThreadFactory(new CustomThreadFactory());
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    // Custom thread factory
    public class CustomThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory{

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            return new Thread(new CustomRunnable(r));
        }

        public static class CustomRunnable implements Runnable {

            private Runnable runnable;


            protected CustomRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
                super();
                this.runnable = runnable;
            }


            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("*******START*******");
                this.runnable.run();

                // I thought we could clear the thread locals here but this line is never executed
                System.out.println("*******FINISH*******");
            }

        }
  }
```

Comment: That will only be used when a new thread needs to be created. As a thread is re-used this obviously won't work. Instead write a `TaskDecorator` which does what you now do in your `CustomThreadFactory`. Which will wrap each submitted task with that behavior.

Comment: yes, it's working, thanks